# Any way to make several object initializations more compact?

Tags: java, initialization

I have the following several HashMap initializations (previously defined elsewhere):

```
hm1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hm2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
.
.
.
hmn = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

One idea would be to store the references into an array and then create the objects within a for loop, but that would allocate unnecessary space. Any ideas?

Comment: Unnecessary space _how_ and _why_ (relative to what you are currently doing)?

Comment: *Why* are you doing what you are currently doing? *What* does having `n` HashMap(s) let you do?

Comment: HashMap put the objects in a random space in the table.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Creating an n length array wouldn't allocate space in the stack apart from the objects' space in the heap?

Comment: That statement (question?) doesn't make much sense. Please clarify.

Comment: Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); allocates heap space. But if I create an array to store all the Map references, (question begins) wouldn't I need extra space in the stack for that? Is it worth it?

Comment: No, the only space on the stack require is the space for the local variable (if there is one in your example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One idea would be to store the references into an array and then create the objects within a for loop, but that would allocate unnecessary space. Any ideas?

The array will use one word for each HashMap reference and ~3 words for the object header.
That is trivial compared with the space occupied by the HashMap objects.

I think what you are doing here (in dismissing the array-based solution) is "premature optimization".

FWIW, I can't think of a *better* approach<sup>1</sup> than using array of HashMap objects.  The `ArrayList` alternative would be better if the number of `HashMap` objects was dynamic, but you are replacing a group of instance variables, so it offers no clear advantages for your use-case<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - You could use reflection, but the code is unnecessarily complicated, and liable to be fragile.  Besides, you may end up using more space to represent the executable code than you save in space to represent the array.  I DO NOT recommend this approach.</sup>

<sup>2 - And it uses more space, though that shouldn't be on your agenda.</sup>

Comment: Hi, I meant space in the stack for creating the array.

Comment: @ddmichael - the array is on the heap not the stack, and the stack space needed to initialize the array will be trivial.  But once again, this is premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to fix a design problem first: use an array (or List) of maps and refer to them by their index in the array, rather than having separate variables:

```
Map<String, Integer>[] maps = new Map<String, Integer>[someNumber];
for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++)
    maps[i] = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

If your variables are fields, put the initialization in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Use ArrayList to store objects. It's dynamic and it wont reserve references until initialisation

```
List<HashMap> array = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    array.add(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
```